# how to run a conditional step in Azure devOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm building my pipelines in the Microsoft devOps forge. I would like to make the test pipeline to export the coverage as an artifact. I run my pipeline on a matrix of python version. I would like to run the exportation only for Python 3.8. How can I specify that a step is conditional ?

Here is my test.yaml file:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    Python37:
      python.version: "3.7"
    Python38:
      python.version: "3.8"
    Python39:
      python.version: "3.9"
    Python310:
      python.version: "3.10"
    Python311:
      python.version: "3.11"

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "$(python.version)"
    displayName: "Use Python $(python.version)"
  - script: python -m pip install nox
    displayName: "Install dependencies"
  - script: nox -s test
    displayName: "Test with pytest"
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1 # this one should be executed only for Python 3.8
    displayName: "Publish coverage"
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: "./htmlcov/"
      artifactName: "coverage"
```

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? What research have you done? Your question needs to show some amount of effort in the steps you've taken to solve the problem on your own; as posted your questions come across as requests for others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this would recommend leveraging an ADO expression to load the task only if the variable version is 3.8. This is different then a condition as the condition will always load the task and skip it if the condition is not met.

```
- ${{ if eq(variable.python.version, '3.8')}} :     
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1 
    displayName: "Publish coverage"
    inputs:
       pathToPublish: "./htmlcov/"
       artifactName: "coverage"
```

Here is a [blog post going into the details between the two](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-if-expressions-and-conditions/ba-p/3737159).

Answer (score -3):

The equivalent of the GitHub action "if" statement is "condition". it can be placed to add execution conditions on jobs, tasks or stages.

in this example to publish the artefact only for version 3.8 use the condition with the following statement:

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1 
    condition: eq(variable["python.version"], "3.8")
    displayName: "Publish coverage"
    inputs:
      pathToPublish: "./htmlcov/"
      artifactName: "coverage"
```

more information can be found in [Azure condition documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages).

Be aware that the variable is called using the `$[]`syntax to be interpreted at run-time. more information about variable syntax can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops)

Comment: This is not accurate as Azure DevOps does support expressions with [expressions and conditional insertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion). Conditions are different as they are evaluated at execution while expression w/ insertion evaluation will occur at pipeline compilation.

Comment: Sorry @DreadFrost but I fail to understand why it's unaccurate. I did use this in my pipelines and it solved exactly my problem, the task is skipped when Python is not 3.8. I see that your answer uses a more elaborate paradigm (the task will not even appear in the job list) but mine mimick what I'm used to see in github actions perfectly. Note that the question is about to "run" on condition so my answer seems to fit.

Comment: It's inaccurate because you claim that Azure Pipelines doesn't have `if` conditionals, but **it does**. You're just misunderstanding that the `condition` parameter in Azure DevOps is *equivalent* to the `if` parameter in GitHub Actions.